# How do I capture JSON response from an API query into a separate output.json file when the below script runs ? #Beginner #Ruby

Tags: json, ruby, api, backend

*I would like to know how can I capture the JSON response that outputs once the above script runs and then create another file file.json where the JSON response is stored.*

```
require "net/http"

url = URI("https://jakunamatata.net/v1/jakunamatata-analytics/summary")

https = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
https.use_ssl = true

request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url)

response = https.request(request)
puts response.read_body;
// prints some json output
```

Comment: Is this what you want `File.write('file.json', response.read_body)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require 'uri'
require 'pathname'
require 'net/http'

# This url does not seem to work - tested with example.com
url = URI("https://jakunamatata.net/v1/jakunamatata-analytics/summary")
path = Pathname.new(Dir.pwd).join('output.json')

Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port, use_ssl: true) do |http|
  request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url)
  http.request(request) do |response|
    File.open(path, 'w') do |io|
      response.read_body do |chunk|
        io.write(chunk)
      end
    end
  end
end

puts "File downloaded to #{path}."
```

This streams the download directly to disk instead of reading the response body into memory. Once you get tired of reinventing the wheel checkout the [`down` gem](https://github.com/janko/down).

Comment: ```require "uri"
require "net/http"

url = URI("https://jakunamatata.net/v1/jakunamatata-analytics/summary")

https = Net::HTTP.new(url.host, url.port)
https.use_ssl = true

request = Net::HTTP::Get.new(url)
# request["Authorization"] = ""

response = https.request(request)
# puts response.read_body;

respData = (response.read_body);

File.open("./response.json","w") do |f|
    f.write(respData)
  end ```